# -bash: cd: <foldername>: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I don’t really understand what I am doing. I am following a tutorial online team aquas hideout 0.0 video, and a website that tells me to

> If you get an error stating ‘fatal: could not set core.filemode to
> false

Which happened to me

> Then run the following commands
>
> ```
> cd
>
> sudo umount /mnt/c
>
> sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata,noatime
>
> cd <folderyouwanttostore>
> ```

And it pops up with the error

Comment: This is wsl2, right?

Comment: It would be helpful to share exactly what you substituted for `<folderyouwanttostore>`